# Ruby require_relative not loading file, not throwing error

Tags: ruby, constants, require

I am having trouble getting constant definitions loaded via an external file. I have narrowed the problem down to the following.

```
require_relative '../../common/config.rb'
A_CONSTANT = 'something'

puts "A_CONSTANT: #{A_CONSTANT}"
```

When I run this as written, it prints the message correctly. The same constant is declared in the file common/config.rb. The relative path is correct for the location of this file. Just for completeness, the above code is in /watir/dashboard/spec/ex.rb. The constant is declared in /watir/common/config.rb.

As I see it, the above code should error out for a duplicate constant declaration. It does not. If I comment out the constant declaration above and rerun, the puts statement shows an error for 'uninitialized constant.' Any ideas what's wrong?

Edit - The contents of the file common/config.rb are below.

```
A_CONSTANT = 'something'
```

On a lark, I changed the filename to common/conf.rb. When I modify the require_relative statement to load the renamed file, I get the results I originally expected. The file is loaded and the second constant declaration throws a warning saying 'already initialized constant.' If I comment out the second declaration, the script runs perfectly.

It appears that the filename 'config.rb' is somehow special when loaded by a relative path. I have use that filename in other scripts where it was in the same folder as the loading script or a sub-folder. This is the first time I have had to move up the tree to load it.

Comment: show how that constant is defined in `config.rb`?

Comment: What is this `'../../` doing?

Comment: Unless Ruby is special, '..' means go up a level in the folder tree. So '../../common' should go up to the watir folder, then down to the watir/common folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby allows redefining constants, and will only print a warning. Some setting in your Ruby is just hiding that warning from you.